# Prove measure of a set is zero

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M},u)$ be a measure space with $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ s.t $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} u(E_i) < \infty$. $E$ is defined to be $E=\{ x\in X: x \in E_i \text{ for infinitely many }i \}$. Prove that $u(E) = 0$.

I notice that $E = \limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} E_k = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{k \geq n} E_k$ and can have that $u(\limsup E_i) \geq \limsup u(E_i)$, but it doesn't seem to be leading to anywhere.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$u(E)\leq u(\bigcup_{k \geq n} E_k)$ for each $n$. This gives $u(E) \leq \sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} u(E_k)$ and this tends to $0$ as $ n \to \infty$ since $\sum u(E_k) <\infty$.